# Building Android app using .NET/C# vs using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

I need to build an app for Android and since I'm a C# monkey (and probably too old to learn Java efficiently), I prefer to do that in .NET. When I was doing research I discovered that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx) also offers a suggestion to do that using HTML/JavaScript (also that within my skill set).

I can't decide between those two approaches and need input. I only have the resources to pick one approach and I fear that I'll get stuck on some practical gotchas if I pick wrongly.

1. Will I need to require my users to download something extra (like a Xamarin runt-time or something) before they can use my app?
2. How can I distribute the app so that it can be obtained the same way as all the others are (Google Store)?
3. Besides it not being native, will I be able to create the same kind of controls, FABs (or whatever it's called) menus etc.

I haven't found much information on the subject (except for Xamarin and a bunch of frameworks basically encapsulating a webpage in an "app" holder). AM I wrong assuming that I can get the same L&F as natives but developing under VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for Xamarin. I use it for our Android apps.

1. Nope! Everything needed is bundled into the application. This does increase the size of the app a bit.
2. You compile to an APK - complete with signing. You can deploy it to Google Play, side-load, etc.
3. You can still design the UI like you would using Java for Android. In fact, when I first started using Xamarin.Android, I used the same Android tutorials for a lot of things with some minor tweaks.

A quick note on #3: I've never used Xamarin.Forms. It's something that was added to ecosystem well after I ported over our Line-of-Business Android apps here at work. I do all the UI stuff "natively."

EDIT:

In regards to your request for clarification on my "XML approach" comment. Please note that some of my terminology be slightly inaccurate.

Android forms come in two parts: the layout resource and the activity class. The layout resource, when dealing with "native" development, uses XML markup. Here's the Hello World layout from Android's site:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" />      
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the activity class, you would assign the layout using this line ("activity_main" being the name of the layout):

Java:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Xamarin.Android:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
```

With Xamarin.Android, you can use the same layout approach via XML or you can try Xamarin.Forms. I'm not sure if you can mix them, though, as I've said: I've never used Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Cool. Regarding (2) - I take it as that the distribution is something that can't be run from VS? I'm so spoiled by Alt+B+H for full redeploy of my site... But you're saying that I'll compile a DLL'ish thingy called APK and shoot it up into the store?

Comment: Regarding (3) - are you saying that it's not possible to create the UI without native code? Or are you saying it's possible but **you** haven't had the joy of testing it?

Comment: For (2): Basically, yea. You'll need to sign the APK, but that's required no matter what approach you take. Xamarin has some more information here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

For (3): It's possible ,but I haven't tested it yet. I actually find the XML approach easy and reliable. I can't speak for Xamarin.Forms.